# Create all possible event pattern in array

Tags: arrays, matlab

I want to generalize the all possible events in array. For example, I have three ball and I want to pick n times. All possible is 3^n events but I want to create all possible event in array like this [1 1 ...1 1; 1 1...1 2; 1 1...1 3; 1 1 ...2 1 ;....]

I used code like this

```
M = 3; % Number of balls. 
N = 3; % Number of draws
result = dec2base(0:M^N-1, M)-'0'+1;
```

but I found the problem that if M > 20; 
The error is Out of memory. Type HELP MEMORY for your options.

I used Matlab version 2013. How can I generalize the code for this question and M >25 in Matlab version 2013?

Please help me

Comment: What is `N` when `M = 25`?

Comment: N is always 3 .

Comment: In that case I can't reproduce the problem. The `result` array is only 15625x3, which is a trivial amount of memory.

Comment: What do you mean? I don't understand.

Comment: I mean that `25^3 == 15625`. Therefore, the size of the array `result` when I run your code is `15625x3` and I don't get any errors. The amount of memory used by this array (since it is an array of doubles) is `15625*3*8 == 375000`, which is a very small amount.